# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification .Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less (Ctrl+F1)  There
>   are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs.  One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible Issue id:
>   GradleCompatible

Dependency in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir:'libs',include:['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    testImplementation'junit:junit:4.12'   
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Let me know if any further information required. I am trying to display Google map on android Emulator and App is launching but google Map is not appearing. i guess its due to above error

Comment: error is shown in the below line

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the error by adding the libraries with something like this:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
}
```